# Yocto build broken when setting a remote rpm repository with https

Tags: image, https, repository, rpm, yocto

I have generated a Yocto image to be used on all my target devices. When that image is running on target devices, it must be able to be updated using a rpm remote repository through https protocol.

To try doing that, I have added a dnf bbappend to my custom layer:

```
$ cat recipes-devtools/dnf/dnf_%.bbappend
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/files:"
SRC_URI += " \
    file://yocto-adv-rpm.repo \
"
do_install_append () {
    install -d ${D}/etc/yum.repos.d
    install -m 0600 ${WORKDIR}/yocto-adv-rpm.repo ${D}/etc/yum.repos.d/yocto-adv-rpm.repo
}
FILES_${PN} += "/etc/yum.repos.d"
```

This is the content of repository configuration file included by dnf bbappend recipe:

```
$ cat recipes-devtools/dnf/files/yocto-adv-rpm.repo
[yocto-adv-rpm]
name=Rocko Yocto Repo
baseurl=https://storage.googleapis.com/my_repo/
gpgkey=https://storage.googleapis.com/my_repo/PACKAGEFEED-GPG-KEY-rocko
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
```

This repository configuration breaks the build process of the image. When I try to build `myimage` recipe, I always get this error:

```
ERROR: myimage-1.0-r0 do_rootfs: [log_check] myimage: found 1 error message in the logfile:
[log_check] Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'yocto-adv-rpm', disabling.
ERROR: myimage-1.0-r0 do_rootfs: Function failed: do_rootfs
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/yocto/yocto/build/tmp/work/machine-poky-linux/myimage/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_rootfs.731
ERROR: Task (/home/yocto/yocto/sources/meta-mylayer/recipes-images/myimage.bb:do_rootfs) failed with exit code '1'
```

However, when I replace the "https" by "http" in "baseurl" variable:

```
baseurl=http://storage.googleapis.com/my_repo/
```

Then the `myimage` recipe is built fine.

The host machine can download files from the https repository using wget:

```
$ wget https://storage.googleapis.com/my_repo/PACKAGEFEED-GPG-KEY-rocko
```

Previous commands works fine, so the problem is not related with the host machine, I think it must be something related with google certificates and yocto stuff.

I found some relevant information inside this file:

```
yocto/build/tmp/work/machine-poky-linux/myimage/1.0-r0/temp/dnf.librepo.log
```

The relevant part:

```
15:56:41 lr_download: Downloading started
15:56:41 check_transfer_statuses: Transfer finished: repodata/repomd.xml (Effective url: https://storage.googleapis.com/my_repo/repodata/repomd.xml)
15:56:41 check_finished_transfer_status: Fatal error - Curl code (77): Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?) for https://storage.googleapis.com/my_repo/repodata/repomd.xml [error setting certificate verify locations:
  CAfile: /home/yocto/yocto/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/curl-native/7.54.1-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: none]
15:56:41 lr_yum_download_repomd: repomd.xml download was unsuccessful
```

Can some of you provide any useful advice to try to fix this?

Thank you in advance for your time! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally fixed my issue removing completely my dnf bbappend recipe from my custom layer and adding this variable to my distro.conf file:

```
PACKAGE_FEED_URIS = "https://storage.googleapis.com/my_repo/"
```

After that, at the end of the build process the image contains a valid /etc/yum.d/oe-remote-repo file and all the necesary stuff to manage it. There is no need to copy "ca-certificates.crt" manually at all.

Also, it's important to execute this command *after* finishing the build of the image:

```
$ bitbake package-index
```

This command generates a "repodata" directory within the package feed needed by the target device once it uses the repo to update packages using dnf client.

Answer (score 0):

I found a temporal hack to fix my issue:

```
$ cp /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt /home/yocto/yocto/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/curl-native/7.54.1-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/etc/ssl/certs/
```

After that, I was finally able to build the image using the "https" repo.

Now I am in the process of fixing this issue in the right way. I'll come back with the final solution.